# Why find piped to xargs mv deleted my files?

Tags: linux, centos, xargs, mv

Today I experienced something unbelievable. My goal was to mv files newer than 7 days to another directory. The directory exist.
I used command:

```
find ./* -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '7 day ago') -type f -print | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ../update_error_handled
```

Then, unbelievably the files were gone, I went to the folder used `ls -lA` and didn't found any files I moved. What happened? CentOS 7.0, there were no directory mount, original files missing, tried to `grep -r "content" /` - found nothing... .

So why it did behave that way?

Beforehand I launched
`find ./* -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '7 day ago') -type f -print` it returned:

```
 ./file66.xml
 ./file67.xml 
...etc.
```

It really do sucks to lose data in such a way.
To clarify: Directory existed before moving files. Directory does not contain my files I tried to move today, only older ones.

Comment: If you want to be sure, that `mv` treats the last argument as a directory, append `/.`. Example: `mv a b c d/.`

Comment: @ceving Thank you for the suggestion! What are the pros and cons of appending `/` (slash) vs `/.` (slash dot) to the dir name? Both seem to be safer than not appending anything, but slash dot is slightly longer, so my preference is for simple slash: `d/` and not `d/.`

Comment: Any possibility of typos, such as extra space somewhere, e.g., destination is `. ./update_error_handled`?

Comment: @TimurShtatland `d` is either a file or a directory and `d/.` is always a directory. `d/` is something in between, which needs a bit interpretation. But it might work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create in advance a directory at `../update_error_handled`?
If not, then all that you have left from the files will be the last one, which will be called `../update_error_handled`.

In order to avoid such mistakes, I always make sure that the destination directory exists, by adding `/.` at the end of the destination directory name.

Unsafe approach:

```
$ rm -rf file dest_dir
$ touch file
$ ls -ld file dest_dir
ls: cannot access 'dest_dir': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 u u 0 Sep 28 11:53 file
$ mv file dest_dir
$ ls -ld file dest_dir
ls: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 u u 0 Sep 28 11:53 dest_dir
```

Using the unsafe approach, `file` was renamed to a file named `dest_dir`.

Safe approach:

```
$ rm -rf file dest_dir
$ touch file
$ ls -ld file dest_dir
ls: cannot access 'dest_dir': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 u u 0 Sep 28 11:54 file
$ mv file dest_dir/.
mv: cannot move 'file' to 'dest_dir/.': No such file or directory
$ ls -ld file dest_dir
ls: cannot access 'dest_dir': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 u u 0 Sep 28 11:54 file
```

Using the safe approach, the `mv` command failed and the file `file` remained intact.

Comment: Well, directory existed beforehand.

Comment: @Fksjii in that case, this issue is not reproducible and I find it hard to believe that anyone will be able to help